# Why can I sometimes edit some list variables with inner function, but not ints in Python

Tags: python

For example, if I use the following code, this will not change nums value

```py
def K():
    nums = 4
    def helper(x):
        nums = 
    helper(3)
    return nums
print(K())

# 4 -> 4
```

However, if nums is a list, I can

```py
def K():
    nums = [0]
    def helper(x):
        nums[0] = x 
    helper(3)
    return nums
print(K())

# [0] -> [3]
```

Comment: First of all, you're not doing anything with `nums = ` in the _helper_ function on the first example. Is that the same on your actual code?

Comment: I suspect you meant `nums = x` in the first code sample.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're actually creating a variable called `nums` that only lives inside your function `helper`

In the second example, `helper` is editing an existing list from the outer scope.

It's just how scopes work for different elements in Python. Variables from the outer scope are as good as read-only. You can read more [here](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/).